# Visual Studio C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Ok, this question is incredibly basic and I'm probably missing something blatantly obvious.  But I just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 because I'm relearning C++.  And I cannot, for the life of me, find how to create a basic C++ project.  Nothing special.  Just a blank C++ project containing files with the .cpp extension.  In VS, I go to File>New Project>Installed>Templates>Visual C++.  All that's in there is xaml related or other far more complicated stuff than what I want to deal with (e.g. Direct3D App).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any template for a console app? That's probably what you're after but I only have VS2010 so can't check it it's still there.

Comment: When you installed Visual Studio it should have asked you what default settings to apply (c#, vb.net, etc).  Which did you select?

Comment: PeterJ: I'll list them: Blank App (XAML), Grid App (XAML), Split App (XAML), Direct2D App (XAML), Direct3D App, DLL (Windows Store apps), Static Library (Windows Store apps) Windows Runtime Component, Unit Test Library (Windows Store apps).  In other words, no.  Maurice Reeves: I don't remember it prompting for that, I remember running the installer and walking away; when I came back it was done.  Should I try a reinstall?

Comment: You should have a Win32 Selection under Visual C++, it has the Win32 Console and Win32 Project templates. It looks like you are just showing the Windows Store Selections.

Comment: try **[Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop)**

Comment: Mark: as far as I can tell, I don't have that.  Alf: I guess that means reinstall, I'll go ahead and give it a shot.

Comment: @gmaster: note that you don't get the [female user depicted on the web page](http://www.microsoft.com//visualstudio/_base_v2/images/products/prod_ex_desktop-hero.jpg) with the default installation. i think she lives in Seattle. so install only if you actually need the technical functionality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find something similar to:

[image]

If you downloaded Visual Studio Express 2012, make sure you obtained the correct version (**Windows**, Web, Phone, etc.).

Comment: I downloaded the version linked by Alf in the comments above, worked like a charm.  Thanks everyone.